# How to use dplyr to merge row data based on a column id

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to determine the best way to collapse a set rows in a dataframe down to one row based on a two column selection.

For example:

```
| State |Fatalities|Injuries|Dmg   |Dmg|year|eventType| PropExp | CropExp |   
| ------|----------|--------|------|---|----|---------|---------|---------|   
| WA    | 1        | 100    |25.00 |0  |1971|HAIL     |1000000  |1        | 0 |   
| WA    | 6        | 200    |25.00 |0  |1972|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 1 |   
| WA    | 2        | 300    |25.00 |0  |1973|SNOW     |1000000  |1        | 0 |   
| WA    | 6        | 900    |65.00 |0  |1973|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 1 |   
| WA    | 4        | 300    |25.00 |0  |1973|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 0 |   
| WA    | 0        | 900    |65.00 |0  |1972|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 1 |
```

The intent is to merge and add the rows from each year by event type... thus we collapse the 1973 TORNADO rows into one row - added the selected row data and creating a new merged data row...

```
| State |Fatalities|Injuries|Dmg   |Dmg|year|eventType| PropExp | CropExp |   
| ------|----------|--------|------|---|----|---------|---------|---------|   
| WA    | 1        | 100    |25.00 |0  |1971|HAIL     |1000000  |1        | 0 |   
| WA    | 6        | 200    |25.00 |0  |1972|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 1 |   
| WA    | 2        | 300    |25.00 |0  |1973|SNOW     |1000000  |1        | 0 |   
| WA    | 10       | 1200   |90.00 |0  |1973|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 1 |   
| WA    | 0        | 900    |65.00 |0  |1972|TORNADO  |1000000  |1        | 1 |
```

Note: I am using an example data set from the Coursera Reproducible Research course - that I have previously completed. The question is not related to the course etc - I am trying to collapse a different data set and I would love to know how to this is done cleanly in R.

What am I missing?

All help gratefully received and appreciated.

Comment: you could transpose the data `t()` and then aggregate with the appropriate `by vars`, then transpose the result back. Or you could take the transpose and reshape.

Comment: Shawn - thanks can you help with a more specific example?

      propertyDamageSummary <- stormData %>%
      filter(STATE == 'WA') %>%
      group_by(eventBeginYear, eventType) %>% ???`

Comment: `df %>% group_by(State, year, eventType) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))`

Comment: Khashaa - Thank you for your help - the solution you posted sums the State value - how do I exclude that? I really do appreciate your help here.

Comment: What is State value?

Comment: Khashaa - It is my mistake I mistyped - your solution worked - thank you!
Good karma flying your way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the `dplyr` solution @Khashaa mentioned in the comments, you can also do this in base R off course:

```
aggregate(cbind(Fatalities, Injuries, Dmg, Dmg.1, PropExp, CropExp) ~ State + year + eventType, data = df, sum)
```

this gives:

```
  State year eventType Fatalities Injuries Dmg Dmg.1 PropExp CropExp
1    WA 1971      HAIL          1      100  25     0 1000000       1
2    WA 1973      SNOW          2      300  25     0 1000000       1
3    WA 1972   TORNADO          6     1100  90     0 2000000       2
4    WA 1973   TORNADO         10     1200  90     0 2000000       2
```

Or as an alternative you could also use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(State, year, eventType)]
```

which gives you the same result.

The disadvantages of both the `data.table` solution and the `dplyr` solution with `summarize_each` is that all the columns are summed. Judging from your desired output, you don't want the `PropExp` & `CropExp` summed. You could achieve that by indicating the columns that have to be summarized with `.SDcols` in `data.table` or with `select` in `dplyr`:

```
# data.table
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum),
          by=.(State, year, eventType),
          .SDcols=c("Fatalities","Injuries","Dmg")]

# dplyr
df %>% group_by(State, year, eventType) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum), -PropExp, -CropExp, -Dmg.1)
```

which both result in:

```
   State year eventType Fatalities Injuries Dmg
1:    WA 1971      HAIL          1      100  25
2:    WA 1972   TORNADO          6     1100  90
3:    WA 1973      SNOW          2      300  25
4:    WA 1973   TORNADO         10     1200  90
```

Off course you can still do this in base R as well:

```
aggregate(cbind(Fatalities, Injuries, Dmg) ~ State + year + eventType, data = df, sum)
```

Comment: Jaap - thank you for help and insights - very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what has been offered, a more clean way of doing this is by using plyr's ddply function:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(year, eventType), numcolwise(sum))
```